# 60 Hz harmonics filtering "disappear" when segmenting the signal into smaller chunks

Tags: filters

I have a signal that I filtered the 60 Hz harmonics using the following python code:

```
q = fs/2/12
b, a = signal.iirnotch(120/(fs/2), q)
data= signal.filtfilt(b, a, data, axis=1)
b, a = signal.iirnotch(60/(fs/2), q)
data= signal.filtfilt(b, a, data, axis=1)
q = fs/2/6
b, a = signal.iirnotch(180/(fs/2), q)
data= signal.filtfilt(b, a, data, axis=1)
b, a = signal.iirnotch(240/(fs/2), q)
data= signal.filtfilt(b, a, data, axis=1)
b, a = signal.cheby2(7, 40, [70 / (fs / 2), 295 / (fs / 2)], btype='bandpass')
data= signal.filtfilt(b, a, data)
```

I'm using `filtfilt` to have a zero delay. I'm characterizing the signal so I don't want any phase distortion. 
I also increased the Bandwidth at 120 Hz because the power at this harmonic is larger or "wider". 
The plot of the absolute spectrum for the whole signal before filtering is like this:

[image]
The plot of the absolute spectrum for the whole resulted signal looks like this (`data` is a multichannel and I'm plotting one of the channels):

[image: absolute spectrum for the whole signal]

You can see that at 120 Hz a suppress happened. Now, when I had a smaller chunk of the data. Where the small chunk is 200 samples and the whole signal samples are ~500K. The absolute spectrum looks like this (after filtering)

[image]

You can see that there are peaks at 120 and 180 Hz noted by red circles. Why is that happening?

The 5 filters responses are shown below. They ordered in the same way as they were ordered in the code above (the first one is at 120 Hz, the second one at 60 Hz, etc) The y-axis represents the amplitude in dB and the x-axis represents the normalized frequency. 
[image]

Comment: Please, explain why you're using `filtfilt`. Post the spectrum of the signal before filtering. Obtain and post the frequency reponse of the five filters you're using. And clarify if the spectrum of the "small chunk" is before of after filtering.

Comment: @MBaz See the edit, please.

Comment: the impulse response of your filters are probably longer than your chunks

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz Based on my understanding, the filtering occurs on the *whole* signal. So, if I divided the signal into smaller chunks the frequency characteristics must hold. Am I right?

Comment: that clarifies that issue, same data , smaller chunks points toward resolution.  are you averaging your chunks or just looking at a fee?

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz I'm just segmenting them using a rectangular window